# Concatenate form_row(form.value)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

Is it possible in Twig with Symfony to concatenate into a single line multiples values from a form.
Like I am choosing a value proposed into a form field, then I want this value appaears into another field from the same form to concatenate it with the value of the new field.

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form_row(form.EPCode) }}
                                {{ dump(form) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form_row(form.NC8Id) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form_row(form.EcoModulation) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ form_row(form.date) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I would like to put {{ form_row(form.EcoModulation) }} value into {{ form_row(form.EPCode) }}.
Thanks for your answers

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, I think you need to use Javascript for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to concatinate multiple variable in twig you can do it like

```html
{{variable1 ~ variable2}}
```

so the '~' operator concatinates 2 values..if this is what you want..but if you want values to be chagned dynamically on client side upon certain selection or fields then you'll need javascript for that.

Comment: Hello SyedKamranAli and Julien B., thank you very much for your help. I have fixed the issue. It was a js issue for  the purpose using datatable library.